# Poll: Administrator tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-burnination

Should the [administrator](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/administrator) tag be nuked?

Comment: IMO, http://serverfault.com/questions/734026/local-administrator-as-default-choice-when-in-domain is a recent, valid use of the tag.  (just a reference)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, nuke it.

Bump: I've started the cleanup of this tag. If anyone else would like to assist, please feel free. Please perform your edits in small batches so that the front page doesn't stay inundated with these edits.

Comment: I am having trouble coming up with a _reason_ for this tag. Who would follow it? Why would they care?

Comment: Agreed. I think it should go. Far too broad to be of any use.

Answer (score 2):

## Transform it to a synonym of an already existing tag.

My candidates would be: [user-management](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/user-management), [authorization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/authorization), [service-accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/service-accounts).

We have a [root](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/root) tag as well. Maybe this should be also handled in the same way.

Comment: Edited the links to be tags in stead, if you disagree feel free to rollback.

Comment: @Reaces It is okay, thanks.

Comment: Maybe the root tag should go as well. At least that one, though, is more limited in scope than "administrator".

Answer (score 2):

This tag not only should be burninated, it should be blacklisted, so that it can never be used again.

Answer (score -2):

Change it!

[admin-account](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/admin-account) or [administrator-account](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/administrator-account) would be a better tag.  [root](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/root) is a tag, with approximately the same number of hits.

Comment: What good would that do, though? What utility do we and other users of the site get from those tags? Who do you anticipate would follow an "administrator-account" tag, and why would it be better for them to follow that tag instead of a more specific tag?

Comment: There are specific security questions and best practices around use of the administrator account.  _Additionally_ tagging the OS in question would be helpful.  There are also multiple approaches to managing "Administrator" in Windows.  LAPS, built-in domain Administrator, etc.  I admit I have not reviewed the 200+ questions using the [tag:Administrator] tag, so I can't say how it was used in the past.

Answer (score -7):

No, it's useful, let's keep it.

(pay no attention to the padding text)

Comment: It seems to be used on a lot of Windows questions, involving the 'administrator' account. The tag-wiki should probably be updated.

Comment: Many of those are permission problems and the much more specific 'permission' tag should be used. Generally, I would say, that in every case the tag 'administrator' was used, a more specific tag should have been chosen.